# appassembler-maven-plugin including the jar in a war pom

Tags: maven

I have a war packaging pom that also builds the jar (via maven-jar-plugin).  Although this is a war there is also a standalone command line tool whose executable is created via appassembler-maven-plugin.

The problem is that appassembler-maven-plugin builds a classpath consisting of the maven lib and the top level pom artifact (in this case the war).  Having the war on the classpath of my standalone app is useless, I need the .jar

Yet I have no clue whatsoever how to get that to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean that by a project of `war` packaging builds a JAR?  BTW, the `appassembler` plugin appears to be doing **exactly** what its documentation says "All dependencies and the artifact of the project itself are placed in a generated Maven repository in a defined assemble directory".  In your case "artifact of the project" translates to the WAR (per your packaging type).